# How i can solver a Error in MariaDB Server

Tags: java, mysql, localhost

Sqlstate 1130 Host Error::'localhost' is not allowed to Connect to this MariaDB server

Solved an error then follow the Below Step

Step 1:- localhost stop and close the localhost
Step 2:- MySQL config file and the going on my.ini file
step 3:-  before that # Here follows entries for some specific programs

## The MySQL server

[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
port= 3306

and start the server

Answer (score 1):

1. localhost stop and close the localhost.
2. MySQL config file and the going on my.ini file.
3. before that # Here follows entries for some specific programs.

The MySQL server

```
[mysqld] skip-grant-tables port= 3306
```

And then Restart Your server

Happy Coding...!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Please verify the user grants if not root user by **Show grants for 'user'@'host'**.
2. If you are connecting through root user then open my.cnf(Linux) or my.ini(windows) and add **skip-grant-tables** and restart the server.
3. Connect to database(root password not required with skip-grant-tables): `use MySQL`
4. `GRANT ALL ON . to root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';`
5. `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
6. Remove or comment the **skip-grant-tables** from my.cnf and restart the server.

I hope this helps!